# Access to elements of const char *arr[] in a function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm passing in a function array of pointers, and want to take the element of array. The Function always returns the last element. Why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> T maxn(T [], int);
template<> const char * maxn(const char *[], int);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *arr_cha[] = {new char[4], new char[5]};
    strcpy(arr_cha[0], "abc");
    strcpy(arr_cha[1], "abcd");

    cout << arr_cha[1] << endl;
    cout << maxn(arr_cha, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}

template<typename T> T maxn(T arr[], int len)
{
    T max = arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<len;i++){
        max = max < arr[i] ? arr[i] : max;
    }

    return max;
}


template<> const char * maxn(const char *arr[], int len)
{
    return arr[0];  
}
```

Console:

```
abcd
abcd
```

All works fine when I'm not allocating strings on heap.

Example:

```
char str1[] = "abc";
char str2[] = "abcd";
char *arr_cha[] = {str1, str2};
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  As is the code wont compile and if we remove the `template<>` to get it to compile then it still can't.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/P4xOnL)

Comment: After I fixed up the code so it would compile, I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hmm.. it doesn't!

Comment: @NathanOliver Code's updated. [Test run](https://ideone.com/nyZdn0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the type you are using in `main` does not match the type of the specialization.  When you call `maxn(arr_cha, 2)` the compiler tries to deduce the parameters (it does not look at the specialization yet as that only happens after deduction).  It deduces that `arr_cha` is defined as a `char*[]`.  This does not match the `const char*[]` that the specialization takes so the specialization is never considered.  Instead the compiler will stamp out a `maxn` from `template<typename T> T maxn(T arr[], int len)` with `T` deduced as `char*`.

In order to get the specialization to work you need

```
template<> char * maxn(char *arr[], int len)
{
    return arr[0];  
}
```

Or, you could just not even specialize the template and instead overload it with

```
char * maxn(char *arr[], int len)
{
    return arr[0];  
}
```

and you'll get the same results.

Comment: Thanks for help. Another question: What should I do if I don' t want to provide access for changing passing strings(in a function) and declare array with const(`const char *arr_cha[]`)?

Comment: @DinirImameev In that case then the specialization would be used.  Because you have `template<typename T> T maxn(T arr[], int len)`, if the type passed to `maxn` doesn't exactly match any of the specializations or overloads then it will be chosen instead as it will produce an exact match while everything else needs a conversion.